# How do I find patents citing a certain article?

Tags: databases, research

How do I find all patents citing a certain article using the [Derwent Innovations Index](https://apps.webofknowledge.com/DIIDW_GeneralSearch_input.do?product=DIIDW&search_mode=AdvancedSearch) / [Web of Science](http://webofknowledge.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there is some way to do this with Google Scholar, but haven't discovered it yet. If you try [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/), you can do something close by searching on a term relevant to the article you are looking for and then trying to find the article in the "Cited Articles" option and selecting it. 
[image]

In addition, there seems to be a new capability at The Lens called [PatCite](https://www.lens.org/lens/patcite). According to that page:

> Using this toolkit you can track, filter, sort, and link scholarly
>   articles that are cited in patents, examine the citing patents, and
>   discover new partners and collaborators. Influence Mapping provides an
>   evidence base to guide decision-making and enables improved public
>   policies and institutional practices.

I haven't used this capability, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a beautiful public tool which shows patents (currently indexed) citing research article. I have not tested in details but seems to work for me. I also believe it doesnot list all the patents but nice way to start.

this requires following steps:-

1. Search your citation in [NCBI PUBMED](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed).
2. Locate the reference in list of result.
3. open the article landing page.
4. Go to bottom **LinkOut** section.
5. Check if '**Cited by Patents in - The Lens**' is present.

If yes then voila you follow the link and it will list all the patents citing that specific research article.

[image]

Comment: That's just for medical papers, though, and it doesn't involve the Derwent Patent Index.

Answer (score 0):

Citation databases make it possible to search cited references; that is, they search for references that are listed in the bibliographies of research publications. In here, users can follow a particular cited reference, or cited author, forward in time to find other articles that have also cited that author or work.

Comment: How I can access Citation databases?

Comment: To cite a work from a periodical in an online database, such as an article, a review, an editorial, or a letter to the editor, begin the entry with relevant facts about the print publication and include the following items in sequence:
Title of the database (italicized)
Medium of publication consulted (Web)
Date of access (day, month, and year)